# Comma before 'and' in adjectival phrase

Tags: commas

I am struggling with whether the following should have a comma or not:

- **The details we have can be linked to and used for your profile.**

or

- **The details we have can be linked to, and used for your profile.**

My instinct would be without a comma; however, I cannot find a rule for this after searching online.

Concerning the title of this post, I was not sure about how to describe the elements in question here, so please forgive me if these are not examples of adjectival phrases. Not knowing this may well have led me to stuggle to find an answer.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A single comma here is not the norm, and I'd say incorrect. Showing the parallel verb structure _and used for_ as a parenthetical (it may be totally omitted without compromising the grammar of the matrix sentence, though obviously dropping important information) by offsetting with _a pair of_ commas (or brackets or dashes) would be quite acceptable, though this adds gravitas to the parenthetical, and I'd say is not the best choice here. Zero punctuation.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin Ashworth. I appreciate your time and effort in helping me with this issue.

Comment: In plain English, no comma is required.